# How to attach a DOM object to a div (propertyeditor)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a small property editor in Javascript. I have a list of objects with some properties (x, y, width, height) for drawing a "`<div>`" inside a div. Im making so that the user can drag images/divs around.

All these objecs are in a list and then I traverse the list and render the view. Next to the view I have a small editor with the properties. I can add multiple of these elements to the editor/viewer and of different kinds (text and images, and maybe other stuff in the future).

[image]

My question is this:

How do I make it so that when editing a property (like the X-coordinate) for the "first/top" box, it updates ONLY the corresponding object in the list (NOT in the view, the view is just being rendered from the list of objects). I'm adding all these in runtime and I have no round-trip to server. I'm cool with having a save button on each item.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow some naming patterns when creating elements and creating property editors. Example, when new image element button is clicked, create image element with id : el_img_01 and property editor for corresponding image element as id : el_img_prop_01.

so for all images will have (el_img_, el_img_prop_), in order to know the img element for a property editor, we can read the property editor id, and remove the 'prop' text from the id to get the associated DOM element.

Comment: So the idea is to have a ID on both the editor and on the object in list. And then when saving from the edítor I find the object on list and assign all the properties from the editor?

Comment: Yeah..right..and id will follow a pattern in such a way given an id from element we shall be able to get the property editor and also the index of the list. all elements will follow el_img_<indexIntoList> and all property editors will follow el_img_prop_<indexInfoList>. If you get an id el_img_prop_01 indicates 1st element in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Several steps here:

1. You need a way to identify the elements, for instance, one
   `id`.
2. You have to be able to select one element and be aware of
   it. You can put a `select` containing all the `id`s, for example.
3. Now you can select the element, you just need to load/save
   the values from your `form`.